# How to change the values of an array and then view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

I want to subtract 273 from the received values of array to view the temperature in Celsius.

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Kelvin: %@",[day objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

Here day is an array of values from which I want to substract value 273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this in two ways

1. in your `cellforRowAtIndex`

   ```
   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Kelvin: %d",[[day objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue] - 273];
   ```
2. where u get the response on that place

   ```
    assume that yourstr=@"345";

    NSString *cal = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [yourstr intValue]-273];
   ```

   add to ur array

   ```
     [day add object: cal];
   ```

   finally u show the normally in your tableview

   ```
    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Kelvin: %@",[day objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Kelvin: %d",[[day objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] intValue] - 273];
```

Give it a try